# Jade: Properly Escape pre Element

Tags: escaping, pug, pre

I am looking to include a comment block within a pre element, but I will get the following error:

```
Line 573: Unexpected token ===
```

My jade `pre` block is:

```
pre(class = "brush:javascript")
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            @Author: Author Name
            @www: www.author-site.ca
            @github: author-github-username

            @package: project-name
            =============================================================================
            Filename: filename.js
            =============================================================================
            This file is responsible for...
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

I read on [Jade Documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) that `pre` elements are escaped by default; however, given the above error, this doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I escape the above code block without getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a dot after the tag (referred in [the Jade documentation as "Block in a Tag"](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/)).

```
pre.(class = "brush:javascript")
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @Author: Author Name
  @www: www.author-site.ca
  @github: author-github-username
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem...

You have to include the escaped content as part of the `pre` (duh?), and not have it nested under it:

```
pre(class = "brush:javascript")
  | /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | @Author: Author Name
  | @www: www.author-site.ca
  | @github: author-github-username
  |
  | @package: project-name
  | =============================================================================
  | Filename: filename.js
  | =============================================================================
  | This file is responsible for...
  |
  | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

So within jade, the `|` indicates this...